# Netbeans GUI editor: How to create a form with JScrollPane top level component?

Tags: netbeans

The Netbeans GUI Editor offers "New -> JPanel form...", but how do I get a JScrollPane as top level component instead of the JPanel?

Of course, a JScrollPane could be put directly under a JPanel, but why using such an unnecessary level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**! if you can follow these simple steps:

- Let come in Tools->Templates->Swing GUI Forms
- Duplicate the template "JPanel Form"

[image: step1]

- Rename the duplicate to "JScrollPane Form"

[image: step2]

- Open the duplicate in the editor

[image: step3]

- "javax.swing.JPanel" changed in "javax.swing.JScrollPane" ... save the file

[image: step4]

- Add a new Swing component to project 
  (Wow! now on the list appear to us our new template file)

  [image: step5]

  - Chose this template and enjoy!

  [image]

Comment: Thanks! Btw, it's javax.swing.JScrollPane in the javax package (instead of the java package)

Comment: Thank you, now it's fixed from java to javax